# Sharepoint 2013: Receive an email when a site page is checked in

Tags: email, approval, notifications

I am an administrator for a Sharepoint site and have been looking into the process of checking in and checking out pages for editing, along with requiring approval before the page is published. Are there any settings that could send me an email anytime someone checks in a page so that I can approve and publish it, rather than having to check for unapproved pages manually every once in a while? I know that you can set up an alert for individual pages but I am looking for something for the whole site.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `alert` or a SharePoint workflow that is fired on item change.

Comment: The alert would be easiest.